# Youtube - autoloop как добавить?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код - выводит плееры с автовоспроизведением на странице, в параметрах задано loop но повтор не срабатывает, читал что то на тему плейлистов, но не понял как подсунуть правильно ссылку.
Код

```
<div id="player0"></div> 
<div id="player1"></div>
<script>
           var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


var player = [];
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player[0] = new YT.Player('player0', {
    height: '220',
    width: '390',
    videoId: 'd7N8ySbq1Bo',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    },
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,
      mute: 1,
      controls: 1,
      loop: 1,
      modestbranding: 1
    }
  });
  player[1] = new YT.Player('player1', {
    height: '220',
    width: '390',
    videoId: 'd7N8ySbq1Bo',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    },

....// остальные плееры
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}


         </script>
```